# Animation glitch (CGAffineTransform + GCD serial queue)

Tags: objective-c, анимация

Добрый день.

Как не допустить подобный глюк?

[[ссылка на ютуб 00:14]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTnZN3MI9U4&feature=youtu.be)

Нужно чтобы анимация исчезновения картинки все же дожидалась полного завершения анимации появления.

```
UIImageView *avatarImageView;

dispatch_queue_t animationQueue = dispatch_queue_create("animationQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
CGFloat someScrollViewOffsetYValue = ... ;

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView {
CGFloat scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

// При скролле вниз до заданной высоты
if (scrollOffset >= someScrollViewOffsetYValue) {

__block UIView *viewInBlock = avatarImageView;
    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = avatarImageView.transform;

    dispatch_async(animationQueue, ^{(void)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            CGPoint center = viewInBlock.center;

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f
                                  delay:0.0f
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                             animations:^{

                                 viewInBlock.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, 0.001, 0.001);
                                 viewInBlock.center = center;

                             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                 NSLog(@"ANIMATE ZOON OUT ---------> FINISH");
                             }];
        });
    });

}


else {

__block UIView *viewInBlock = avatarImageView;

    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = avatarImagaView.transform;

    dispatch_async(animationQueue, ^{(void)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            CGPoint center = viewInBlock.center;
            viewInBlock.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, 0.001, 0.001);
            viewInBlock.center = center;

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f delay:0.1f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
                viewInBlock.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                NSLog(@"ANIMATE ZOON IN ---------> FINISH");

            }];

        });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь Ваша `animationQueue` бесполезна + с `[UIView animateWithDuration...` проблематично сделать без дополнительных переменных. Используйте `CABasicAnimation`.
Пример сделал по нажатию на кнопку, просто доделайте под свои нужды:

```
- (IBAction)clickAction:(UIButton *)sender {
    double toValue = isShow ? 1 : 0.001;
    double fromValue = [(CALayer *)[_avatarImageView.layer presentationLayer] transform].m11; // Здесь мы берем текущую позицию
    double duration = 0.3 * fabs(toValue - fromValue); // Высчитываем длительность анимации 
    CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(toValue, toValue);
    _avatarImageView.transform = scaleTransform;
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:toValue];
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:fromValue];
    animation.duration = duration;
    animation.timingFunction = isShow ? [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut] : [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.removedOnCompletion=NO;
    [_avatarImageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transformScale"];
    isShow = !isShow;
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, на днях обязательно проверю